# Timsort execution time in Python

Tags: python, sorting, array-algorithms, timsort

I'm studying some sorting algorithms and their execution times. I implemented some algorithms in Python and I am measuring how long they take to sort some arrays.
I found that Python natively implements Timsort as sorting algorithm for lists.
However, I wanted to compare the native Timsort with an implementation I found on GitHub ([this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheAlgorithms/Python/master/sorts/timsort.py)).
How is it possible that the native implementation takes 0.000630140304565 seconds to sort an array of 51200 elements while the implementation I linked before takes 40.7546050549 seconds to sort the same array?

[EDIT]
To get time I use "time.time()" before and after the execution of the sorting algorithm and then I just make the difference.

I expected the native implementation to be faster, but not so much. The fact is that I have implemented also other sorting algorithms in Python and, for example, Merge-Sort takes 0.148133039474 seconds to sort the same array. 
I did not expect this big difference between Merge-Sort and the Python implementation of Timsort.

[EDIT2]
So the problem is that the implementation I found is not efficient and is not really Timsort. 
Sorry guys, I just found that Timsort was theta(nlgn) and I believed that was the right implementation. Now the problem is: does an efficient Python implementation of Timsort exist?

Comment: What is the code you're using to time the algorithm?

Comment: One advantage is that the native timsort is... it's native. It's running in C, not Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Objects/listobject.c#L1015

Comment: Because the native implementation of python is written in C and then imported into python. In contrast the github sort algorithm is written in pure python. C is a much faster language.

Comment: To get accurate timings, it's better to use [perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), or [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#module-timeit).

Comment: What is described there as "timsort" is surely not timesort. Timsort has a ["gallopping mode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Galloping_mode) but there is no trace of it in that code. It seems just a pseudo-very-simplified-timsort-variant to me.

Comment: Also: the algorithm is written in a completely inefficient way. Look at how it merges the lists `[left[0]] + merge(left[1:], right)` . This type of operation is going to create an enormous amount of temporary lists, in fact I believe the `merge` function defined there is not linear but quadratic (`[x] + merge(...)` takes O(n) time instead of amortized O(1)).

Comment: See this more recent post on stackexchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232826/timsort-implementation-in-python

Comment: Please see this more recent stackexchange query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361100/timsort-execution-time-in-python

Answer (score 0):

24 November 2020

A very complete and tested python implementation of timsort from October 2018 (before the original question here was posed) is here:

https://gist.github.com/ruminations/89a045dc0ef7edfb92304a0de0752ee0

The commentary includes useful links for the purpose of education.